# Find which dependency uses cgo

Tags: go, glibc

I'm getting the following error when I compile my Go binary locally and then run it on my docker container:

```
my-server: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by my-server)
my-server: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by my-server)
```

Everything works fine if I set `CGO_ENABLED=0` when compiling. None of my code uses glibc, so I'm just curious which of my dependencies is pulling it in. Is there any way to query which dependency requires this?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/655kax/how_to_figure_out_whats_using_cgo/
Check if this helps

Answer (score 0):

> which of my dependencies is pulling it in

Running `LD_DEBUG=files my-server |& grep 'needed by'` will produce lines similar to:

```
   2310307:     file=libtinfo.so.6 [0];  needed by ... [0]
   2310307:     file=libc.so.6 [0];  needed by ... [0]
```

which should answer your question.